# Create context for a part of code

Tags: c#, session

So here is the question : is there any way to create a *Context* that will be share only a part of the code. I don't really know how to explain it, so I will make an example.

Suppose that I have :

```
using(Context ctx = new Context())
{
    ctx.Set("abc","abc");
    method1();
    method2();
}
```

and (same for method 2) :

```
public void method1()
{
    Context ctx = Context.Instance();
    string abc = ctx.Get("abc");
}
```

The goal is that the `Context.Instance()` in the methods return the object created in the using but it must remains thread safe. What I mean is that if call is made from outside a using, or inside another using at the same time, it will return the context according to the using. And `Context.Instante()` will return a new `Context` if not exist (or null, I will adapt after, that's not the point).

I know this is not classic way of doing it but I don't want to have to pass the context at each call. The real method will have lots of subs methods and only the lasts will need it, but it must be common since the beginning.

The goal is to create one transaction that will be shared to all (and only) submethods, but the top methods don't have access to EF classes. The only solution I have is to use the session to store my EF Context, or in static for batches since they don't have session. That's my goal, but the problem is much more generic.

I hope I'm clear, don't hesitate to ask questions. And add tags since I don't really know what tags add.

Thanks !

**EDIT**

I might not have been clear enough. Singleton is not enough, the static is shared between all the instance. If two call to the using are done in the same time by two different user, the Context will be the same to them, but I want them different.

Ideally, I would like to allow things like :

```
using(Context ctx = new Context())
{
    ctx.Set("abc","abc");
    method1();
    using(Context ctx = new Context())
    {
        ctx.Set("abc","def");
        method2();
    }
    method1();
}
```

But I think I ask too much.

Comment: Sounds like you are describing a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: Is this so you don't need to pass the connection string in every time you use a new context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your Context.Instance() method manage a [thread static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) variable. The first call can create the instance, other calls can use it, and at the end of the using of the first call, you destroy it.

Using the thread-static approach, no multi threading problems should arise, since each thread has its own instance. In a single thread, every 'next method execution' will use the same instance.

UPDATE:

Some code. If I debug through it, only a single context is created, the second using statement receives the same context as the first using statement.

```
class Context : IDisposable {
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Context _instance;
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static int _instanceCounter;

    public static Context Instance() {
        if (_instanceCounter == 0) {
            _instance = new Context();
        }
        _instanceCounter++;
        return _instance;
    }

    private static void Release() {
        _instanceCounter--;
        if (_instanceCounter == 0) {
            if (_instance != null)
                _instance.Dispose();
            _instance = null;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Release();
    }
}

public class Test {
    public void Test1() {
        using (var context = Context.Instance()) {
            // do something
            Test2();
        }
    }

    private void Test2() {
        using (var context = Context.Instance()) {
            // identical context as in Test1
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Just a question why do you call `_instance.Dispose()` in `Release()` since the only way to get into Release is by using a Dipose ? I failed to understand why it need to call Release one time much than the number of instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Singleton design pattern, here's a template. It will ensure only one instance of a class is created, and that all parts of your program are using the same one

```
public class Singleton {

 private static Singleton instance; 

 private Singleton(){ // note private constructor

  // intialize code here
 }


 public static Singleton GetInstance(){

  if(instance == null){

   instance = new Singleton();
 }
   return instance;
 }

}
```

}

Also in a multi threaded environment you need to perhaps imagine a case where two threads can enter your GetInstance method when Instance is null, and both end up initializing separate instances of the Singleton class.

To retrieve the instance you would call `Singleton.GetInstance()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ThreadStatic as Maarten said, something like this might work:

```
public class Context : IDisposable
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Context context;

    private Context(Guid id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public Guid Id
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public static Context Instance()
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            context = new Context(Guid.NewGuid());
        }

        return context;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context = null;
    }
}
```

If you create a console app with the following code in it, you should get an idea of how it works.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action action = () =>
    {
        using (var context = Context.Instance())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} - Context Id {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, context.Id);

            using (var context2 = Context.Instance())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} - Context Id {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, context.Id);
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    };

    Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(action);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you want to make sure the context is only actually disposed by the outermost using statement, you will need to count how many times instance is called per thread too.

Comment: You're not actually disposing the instance.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually a pretty nasty design because you're re-using a single object multiple times but yeah I forgot to add `if (context != null) { context.Dispose(); }` before setting `context=null;`